# python - How to count and take averages on a tuple with Paired values

Tags: python, tuples

I am new to python. Can you please help me with this? I have a tuple lets say `(100, (10.0, 20.0, 30.0))`. I need to write a function which will take this as an input and return `(100, (3, 20.0))` where `3` is the value count and `20` is the value of average.

Comment: That's an interesting task. If you run into issues while coding it that can't be solved by doing Google searches and reading documentation, let us know.

Comment: A few hints: you need to take the `len` of your inner tuple, and the average is nothing more than the `sum` of the elements divided by the `len`.

Comment: read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). Writing this comment takes longer than learning about tuples. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this with numpy:

```
import numpy
def myfunction(mytuple):
    myresult=(mytuple[0],(len(mytuple[1]),numpy.mean(mytuple[1])))
    return myresult
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a starter code. :

```
def function(tup):

    f = tuple()
    a = len(tup[1])        ## Finds the length of the list of numbers
    b = sum(list(tup[1]))  ## Converts the second item of the tuple into a list and finds the sum

    f = ( tup[0] , (a, b/float(a)) ) ## The final result

    return f
```

Comment: You don't need the line `f = tuple()`.

Comment: Just to make things clear. He had mentioned he is new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the inputs! I was able to build the function using the information you guys have provided.

```
def getCountAndAverages(a):
CountAndAverage=[]
for i in range(0,(len(a))):
    if (i%2)!=0:
        summation=sum(list(a[i]))
        count=len(a[i])
        average=summation/count
        CountAndAverage.append((count,average))
    else:
        CountAndAverage.append(a[i])
mytuple=tuple(CountAndAverage)
return(mytuple)
```